# Facebook graph api 2.9 get total count of friends only

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get JSON with all fields related to user_friends scope. However, from version 2.0 API returns mostly empty `data[]`(if non of user's friend uses this app). Currently what I get is:

```
 "friends": {
      "data": [],
      "summary": {
         "total_count": 142
      }
   }
```

I want to extract only `summary` with total count of user's friends. So what I want to get is

```
 "friends": {
      "summary": {
         "total_count": 142
      }
   }
```

Is this even possible?
I didn't find anything helpful about this in documentation, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, that is not possible - you will always get the `data` structure. But if you are not interested in individual friends at all (even if they are app users), then specify a limit of 0 - then the `data` structure will always be empty, even if the user has friends using the same app that would otherwise show up in there.

Comment: @CBroe I thought so, just wanted to make sure. To set data limit of 0 is a good idea, thanks